# Precision of obj-c float on Mac vs c++ float on PC x64

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a 2 program :

- C++ client running on x64 computer compiled with VS2010.
- Obj-C server running on iOS simulator compiled with Xcode 4.2

I'm sending over the network an array of float values from the server to the client,
and some of them (not all) are different at 10^-3 (i.e -1.002229 vs. -1.000000 // 0.331106 vs. 0.3333333).

They're is at the same time both bad and good version of same number (array[4] will be 1.00000 and array[6] will be 1.002229)

To print those values and spot the differences I use printf("%f", array[n]);

Unfortunately, I have no access to the source code that send them over the network (I have only dll version - can't use another one - no way to use double instead of floats -  no way to get the source code).

Does someone have any possible explication of this problem ?

Comment: They may just be flipped bits, sending a data over a network isn't free from errors, unless you use a reliable data transfer protocol. Do you always get the same values or they're kinda random?

Comment: it's not always the same values, just made a new try : 1.00000 can now be 1.00000 (good) or 1.001000 (bad)

Comment: You should create some mechanism to check that the bits are not flipped, see this: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvChecksums.html

Comment: even on TCP this problem is possible ?

Comment: No, TCP implements a reliable data transfer mechanism. There must be some other problem then.

Comment: why not serialize the data in a single archive and then de-serialize the archive so you can feel free to not think about any protocol ?

Comment: I'm actually streaming 3d position of vertex, i want the transmission to be as fast as possible

Comment: An array is already serialized data.

Comment: @IggY do you know what is sizeof(float) in the C++ client?

Comment: sizeof (float) == 4 (C++) and also sizeof (float) == 4 (Obj-C) 
The transfert protocol is using TCP whireshar says

Comment: Try this to see if its the bits: create a `union` of a `float` and a 32-bit int, at each end put in the float value and use `printf` to show the int value as hex. Are the bits changing? If they are changing try sending the 32-bit "integers" over the line using the union for "conversion", that should rule out fp code in your DLL.